# Add cookies to dependancy injected HttpClient in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

how can I add cookies to `HttpClient` used in injected service ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests))? I have created some service `ApiService` and that service has `HttpClient` injected just like `CatalogService` in tutorial. Problem is, in order to communicate with external API, my service and it's `HttpClient` must have a token which was previously received by another API called `IdentityService` using `LoginService`. So, when login is completed in fronted web app:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Token)) {
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = ValidateToken(user.Token);
    if (principal != null) {
        AuthenticationProperties p = new AuthenticationProperties();
        p.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7);
        p.IsPersistent = Persistant;
        p.RedirectUri = Request.Query.ContainsKey("ReturnUrl") ? Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].ToString() : "";

        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, p);

        // those cookies are lost when ApiController is called - new instance of http client replaces this one
        var apiService = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IApiService));
        var s = apiService as ApiService;
        s.SetClientCookies("token", user.Token);

        return new RedirectToPageResult("../Index");
    }
}

return BadRequest("Invalid token");
```

`SetClientCookies` currently looks like this but it isn't working because ApiService constructor gets a new instance of HttpClient:

```
public class ApiService: IApiService {
    public static readonly NLog.Logger log = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private HttpClient _client;
    static string BaseUrl = "https://localhost:44365/api";

    public ApiService(HttpClient client) {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task < List < DbTest >> GetAccounts() {
        var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + "/account");

        if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot retrieve login");
        }

        var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var accounts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < DbTest >> (content);

        return accounts;
    }

    public void SetClientCookies(string key, string value) {
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", key + "=" + value);
    }
}
```

Result is, when API is called with `HttpClient`, there is no "token" cookie... Any idea how to change this so `ApiService`'s `HttpClient` doesn't lose its cookies which are received on login?

Related `Startup.cs` code is this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ILoginService, LoginService>("identityServiceClient");

services.AddHttpClient<IApiService, ApiService>("apiServiceClient")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(client => {
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
    });
```

Comment: remove HttpClient and add «IHttpClientFactory factory»  in your constructor. Then call «_client = clientFactory.CreateClient("apiServiceClient")». I think this should work to get the right instance which holds the cookies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possibility would be to add a cookie container to the service collection

```
var container = new CookieContainer();
services.AddSingleton(container);
```

and use that instance when registering the client

```
services.AddHttpClient<IApiService, ApiService>(client => {
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44365/api").
}).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() {
        CookieContainer = container,
        UseCookies = true
});
```

Now the container can be resolved and manipulated as needed.

```
var container = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<CookieContainer>();
container.Add(BaseUrl, new Cookie("token", user.Token));
```

Comment: Magnificent! Works like a charm with slight change while resolving: 
`var container = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(CookieContainer)) as CookieContainer;
container.Add(new Uri("https://localhost"), new Cookie("token", user.Token));`